Draw image inside HTML canvas using specific width/height
I have a Canvas setup as follows:
<canvas id="canvas" style="width: 1200px; height: 500px;"></canvas>

I then want to upload a file and add it to the canvas, but drawn using a specific width and height, as follows:
var fileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.onload = function( event ){
    var image = new Image();

    image.onload = function() {
        canvasCtx.drawImage( image, 0, 0, 400, 200 );
    };

    image.src = event.target.result;
}

fileReader.readAsDataURL( file );

This image is added but it is using the full width and height of the canvas.  I've tried scaling it, but can't seem to get it working.

Unable to reproduce, canvasCtx.drawImage( image, 0, 0, 25, 25 ) gives me a 25z25 image on the canvas

Canvas size is set by defining width and height properties:
<canvas id="canvas" width="1200" height="500"></canvas>

That's the size of two-dimensional context and you can draw on this canvas. It's always in points. Otherwise you might use relative units, eg. percents:
<canvas id="canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas>

How to draw on such canvas? How to determine where to put an image? That's why there is a difference between how big is a drawing context, and how to place the canvas in webpage.
You can set the canvas to be 1200x500 and resize it to fit the parent container at the same time:
<canvas id="canvas" width="1200" height="500" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas>

I hope it clears up your doubts.

This completely misses OPs question.

I believe it doesn't miss the question. The published code seems to be correct, but the problem is with default canvas dimensions.

drawImage method has 9 parameters.
drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)

You can stretch the image in given sizes like this:
canvasCtx.drawImage( image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, 0, 0, 400, 200);

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage for more information.
Also, you should set width and height your canvas object for proper view. Proper code sample:


const fileReader = new FileReader();
const {width, height} = document.getElementById('container').getBoundingClientRect();
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
const canvasCtx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

fileReader.onload = function( event ){
    const image = new Image();

    image.onload = function() {
        const ratio = Math.max(image.width/400, image.height/200)
        canvasCtx.drawImage( image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, 0, 0, image.width/ratio, image.height/ratio);
    };

    image.src = event.target.result;
}

function handleFile() {
    const file = document.querySelector("input[type=file]").files[0];
    fileReader.readAsDataURL( file );
}
html,  body {
    color: #222;
    background: #bbb;
    font: 14px monospace;
    user-select: none;
}

canvas {
   background: #fff;
}
<div>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="handleFile()"/>
    <div id="container" style="width: 1200px; height: 500px;">
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>



